# Separable polynomial and characteristic of field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a monic separable polynomial over $F$ such that the set of all roots of $f(x)$ in the algebraic closure $\bar{F}$ is a subfield of $\bar{F}$.

Then, the splitting field of f(x) over $F$ is the subfield of $\bar{F}$. However, how to know the following properties

> $ \textbf{ Question }$
>
> (1) $F$ has non-zero characteristic $p$
>
> (2) $f(x) = x^{p^n} - x $ for some $n\geq 1$

??

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I don't know why $F$ has non-zero characteristic $p$

Comment: As you say **nothing** about what $F$ is, then there is no reason to suppose it ha any given characteristic.

Comment: For starters, the set of all roots of $f(x)$ is finite. If they form a field ... the rest follows pretty much immediately from standard proofs about the existence/uniqueness of finite fields.